# How do I find the "top - level" .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04

I have roundcube installed on a server i'm working on now. But the rules that deny access to 3 files as shown [here](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/wiki/Installation#protect-your-installation), in the roundcube root, aren't being applied. I know this because I can browse the config, temp and logs files via a browser.

I'm I right to assume that there's another .htaccess file not allowing these rules to be applied?
and if yes, how do I do I find this file and make sure that the rules are applied?
If no, what else would cause this kind of behaviour?

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Most likely you forgot to enable the interpretation of such dynamic configuration files. Take a look at apache `AllowOverride` directive.

Comment: Apart from that: it usually is a very good idea to place such directives in the real http servers host configuration instead of relying on such dynamic configuration files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server.

Comment: @arkascha could add abit more detail. I'm abit new to the use of .htaccess files. The roundcube docs talk about the AllowOverride, but I don't know where to place this directive

Comment: You need to place that in the http servers host configuration to enable the usage of such dynamic configuration files. This reads as if you did not bother to look into the documentation of the tools you use... Start reading there: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride